# Distinction between Samekh and Sin in the Yemenite tradition

Tags: pronunciation, language, yemenite-temani

As far as I know, in the Yemenite tradition there is a distinct sound for all consonants for the exception of Samakh and Sin. [In the Wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yemenite_Hebrew#Distinguishing_features) it says that both sin and samakh are pronounced identically as /s/. However, I have found two responses here of that at least in in some sub-dialects of Yemenite Hebrew, there was exists or at least at some point existed a distinction between the two letters.

Examples of this are [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67401/why-is-hebrew-the-holy-language-so-messy/67403#67403) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/relationship-between-samekh-and-sin/66847#66847). I've searched around the web looking to see if there was any other source that would indicate the existence of between the voiceless sibilants. After much searching, the only lead I could find of people talking about a difference was on the old teimani website chayas [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170319050530fw_/http://www.chayas.com/backup/pronounceparchi.htm#parch) as a comment from the site admin. I can't trust the source for sure but if such a distinction did exist in recent times, could any of you present me a good source that talks about the difference between samakh and sin according to the Yemenites, if it exists?